# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.mmbt' - How to fix it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, huggingface

I have used the code below (reference here: https://huggingface.co/classla/xlm-roberta-base-multilingual-text-genre-classifier) several times but actually I'am not able to execute it since the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.mmbt' occurs without any apparent reason.

I run the code on google colab.

**Pip**

```
!pip install transformers
!pip install simpletransformers
```

trasformers: version 4.30.2

simpletransformers: version 0.63.11

python: version 3

**Code**

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel
model_args= {
            "num_train_epochs": 15,
            "learning_rate": 1e-5,
            "max_seq_length": 512,
            "silent": True
            }
model = ClassificationModel(
    "xlmroberta", "classla/xlm-roberta-base-multilingual-text-genre-classifier", use_cuda=True,
    args=model_args
    
)
predictions, logit_output = model.predict(["How to create a good text classification model? First step is to prepare good data. Make sure not to skip the exploratory data analysis. Pre-process the text if necessary for the task. The next step is to perform hyperparameter search to find the optimum hyperparameters. After fine-tuning the model, you should look into the predictions and analyze the model's performance. You might want to perform the post-processing of data as well and keep only reliable predictions.", 
                                        "On our site, you can find a great genre identification model which you can use for thousands of different tasks. With our model, you can fastly and reliably obtain high-quality genre predictions and explore which genres exist in your corpora. Available for free!"]
                                        )
predictions
# Output: array([3, 8])

[model.config.id2label[i] for i in predictions]
# Output: ['Instruction', 'Promotion']
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e269f817f0ec> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/simpletransformers/classification/multi_modal_classification_model.py in <module>
     45     BertTokenizer,
     46 )
---> 47 from transformers.models.mmbt.configuration_mmbt import MMBTConfig
     48 
     49 from simpletransformers.classification.classification_utils import (

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.mmbt'
```

Comment: https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/1539

Answer (score 3):

!pip install transformers==4.24.0
!pip install simpletransformers==0.63.11

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```html
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!sudo apt install python3-pip
%pip install transformers==4.30.2
%pip install simpletransformers
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).